# how to insert data from file line by line into request in python code

Tags: python, file

I need to insert data from file line by line in python request

example

user.txt

```
1
2
3
```

and script to open file user.txt

```
user=open("user.txt","r").readlines()
```

and request

```
r = request.get('http://example.com/r='+user)
```

how to make can request line by line user.txt in request

example

```
http://example.com/r=1
http://example.com/r=2
http://example.com/r=3
```

not like this

```
http://example.com/r=['1','2','3']
```

Comment: Have you learnt about loops?

Comment: how to do that?

Comment: @VickyzSetiawan How to learn? Read the [tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html).

Answer (score 2):

You could iterate over the lines you've read:

```py
with open("user.txt","r") as f:
    for line in f:
        r = request.get('http://example.com/r=' + line)
        # do something with r
```

Comment: the code only read the last line in user.txt only example.com/r=3 not line by request like example

Comment: @VickyzSetiawan You nee to use `r` in each iteration of the loop, as the comment says

Answer (score 0):

You can use cycle like this:

```py
with open("user.txt","r") as users:
    for user in users.readlines():
        response = request.get('http://example.com/r=' + user)
        # do something with the response, ex store response.json() somewhere
```

Comment: −1 because you're fake.

Comment: @enzo What do you mean by that? oO

Comment: the code only read the last line in user.txt only example.com/r=3 not line by request like example

Comment: Did you store the response somewhere? You should add some code instead of `# do something with the response, ex store response.json() somewhere`

Comment: i'm store the response into function i wat to try again with your code. thanks

Comment: after add your code into fuction still only read last line

Comment: Could you please update the question to show what you want to do with the request results?